# How to fix '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7 in 1.6?

Tags: java, android

I have a Java 1.6 Android project. I have a third-party code that does not compile:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
//...
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
//...
new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
```

It says: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

I do not want to switch my project to 1.7. I have changed that line to

```
new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
```

and it compiles fine now.

But is my fix correct? What does Java 1.7 do with empty brackets?

**Update**

That new object is passed to function that accepts `HttpEntity<?>` argument. I understand the idea of type inference, but I do not understand what does 1.7 compiler infer from the given code line.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Comment: where is the new object assigned to? How is that variable defined?

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks, bit I still do not understand what does 1.7 compiler infer from that line.

Comment: @sidgate the new object is passed to some function that accepts `HttpEntity<?>` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fix is almost correct and anyway not dangerous.

`Object` is the root of the hierarchy and <> means "let the compiler infer the type", so any type that would have been inferred in 1.7 would be a specialization of `Object` anyway.

After having seen your update: `<?>` actually means "wildcard" [(see here)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), so `Object` is fine.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the first part of the line there, I'm sure a HttpEntity wasn't created to just throw it away (check the type of the reference it's saved to).

Java <1.7 requires this:

`SomeGenericClass<String> foo = new SomeGenericClass<String>();`

Java 1.7 allows this as shorthand:

`SomeGenericClass<String> foo = new SomeGenericClass<>();`

Answer (score 2):

The diamond operator is just thought to reduce the unnecessary effort of repeatedly having to type the generic in an assignment.

Instead of

```
ArrayList<MyClassWithThatStupidLongName> list = new ArrayList<MyClassWithThatStupidLongName>();
```

You could just use:

```
ArrayList<MyClassWithThatStupidLongName> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This was however introduced in Java 7, and as you seem to need the code working for a lower version, you'll have to add all those Generics back in, as in my first listing.

Answer (score 1):

Your fix is correct. It would be better to use the exact (generic) type of `HttpEntitiy.

The idea behind the `<>` operator is just to reduce verbosity in places where the compiler can infer the generic type from the code implicitly.

As was described in this [post](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)

> The Diamond Operator reduces some of Java's verbosity surrounding
>   generics by having the compiler infer parameter types for constructors
>   of generic classes

The need for such operator came from the verbosity of declaring new instances of generic types. In Java versions before 1.7 you had to define generics this way:

```
List<MyClass> myClassCollection = new List<MyClass>();
```

Which is obviously redundant as the compiler can easily understand the type that should be in the construction of the object.

Another great improvement that comes with this operator is the return of a generic type:

Before java 1.7:

```
public List<MyClass> getMyClassCollection() {
   if(some condition) {
       return new ArrayList<MyClass>();
   } else {
       return LinkedList<MyClass>();
   }
}
```

After java 1.7:

```
public List<MyClass> getMyClassCollection() {
   if(some condition) {
       return new ArrayList<>();
   } else {
       return LinkedList<>();
   }
}
```

This might seem trivial, but in fact there might be flows in which you can spare some such declarations. The huge advantage comes when you want to change your code. If you now change the method to return `List<MyClassChild>` (where `MyClassChild` extends `MyClass`) you **only need to change one place** and not several places.