# Facebook SDK 4.x errors with JDK 1.7 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, java-8, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to use the latest Facebook SDK (4.2 as of today) in an Android project, and I'm using Eclipse (if I'm not mistaken, this version no longer includes an Eclipse project so I had to create one with the included files).

I'm getting the following error message:

`[FacebookSDK] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.`

Doing Fix Project Properties does nothing. However, when I manually set the project to use 1.6, I get the following error:

`'< >' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7`

Any tips on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, what I did was what's mentioned in this answer:

[How to fix '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7 in 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677597/how-to-fix-operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-level-below-1-7-in-1-6)

Specifically, I left the version as 1.6 and simply entered the class type that is expected in the <>.

So for example, instead of

`ArrayList<ModeHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();`

I would simply enter the class:

`ArrayList<ModeHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<ModeHandler>();`